# What exactly happened at the Trillia Massacre?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

The only thing we seem to know about it so far is that it involved rathtars, as The Force Awakens and Wookieepedia say. But is there anything else about it in canon or legends? I get the impression that Finn either witnessed it or knew somebody who witnessed it, as he is shocked to learn that Han Solo is hauling rathtars. He definitely has seen rathtars before. Do you think we will learn more about it in the future?

Comment: What ever it is, it would only be canon, as rathtars originated in *The Force Awakens*.

Answer (score 7):

**We don't know.** It's only mentioned in the film (and the subsequent novelisations) as a [*noodle incident*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident). Evidently a single(?) rathtar caused a significant loss of life, probably somewhere called Trillia. It was a "massacre", if you feel like getting florid.

> *Finn moved closer to Rey. “I know of a perfect example that explains everything you’d ever want to know about rathtars.” She eyed him expectantly. “Ever hear of the Trillia Massacre?”
>
>   She shook her head. “No.”
>
>   “Good,” he replied. **And that was the extent of his explanation, briefly referencing an incident so vile and depraved that he wished only to assure himself she knew nothing about it.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> *He fought, he kicked, he bit, and he punched. The tentacle’s viselike grip only tightened around his waist, dragging him toward the rathtar’s mouth. Like the gangster before him, **and those poor beings in the Trillia Massacre, Finn was going to be munched into hundreds of pieces.**
>
>   He didn’t hear his own screams. He only heard Rey calling out his name.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: Wasn't there a mention also somewhere else (like the story about finn/finns forestory)?  I think I remember reading something that the massacre was mentioned there during training.

Comment: @Thomas - Finn's backstory is in "Before the Awakening". There's nothing about Trillia, a massacre or anything relating to beasts.

Comment: ok then I had misread (wasn't sure as I never got that book but thought I read from someone that it was mentioned). tnx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Finn was personally involved. Id rather say its a widely known event and everyone talks about it with fear. Kind of like 9/11 or Sandy Hook. Either way the way its told the event seems to have a lot of weight, like maybe after the massacre the creature became illegal to own. I loved that throw away line though. It made the SW galaxy feel more lived in, like there is history and things that people should know.

Comment: Yeah, but what actually happened?

Answer (score -3):

I don't know what happend but the best answer is that a bunch of rathtars got loose and killed a whole bunch of people.

Comment: If you don't know what happened, can you explain how this can be the best answer?

Answer (score -3):

I feel like someone done something wrong like a Jedi that let the rathtars out so all the Jedi fought the rathtars the rathtars killed Jedi and even people so the trillia massacre is a massacre of psycho creatures.

"from Star Wars"

Comment: Can you back this up with evidence from canon?

Answer (score -4):

It appears to have been trillions of people that got killed because someone either purposely or accidently let loose Rathars to kill people and it became a wide world story.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Good to have you here. I wonder, do you have anything to back this answer up with?

Comment: It's "Trillia", not "trillion".